# Ordering the relationship within a Graph Database (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am discovering the graph database logical, reading the Graph Database Handbook of O'Reilly. I am enthusiastic, but still have some question.

My first questions is about relationship. Suppose I want to modelize relation between texts and manuscripts contening them.

So I will have two types of node (two labels):

- Manuscripts
- Texts

One manuscript can contain multiple texts, and one texts can be contained in multiple manuscripts. So I will have something like `(ms:MS {identification}) -[:CONTAINS]->(txt:TXT {identification})`.

But the question is how could I store and request the order of the texts in a a manuscriptif. Should I add "order" propertie to the `CONTAINS` relationship? What about performance in requesting for:

- get the order list of the texts contening in a specific manuscript
- know in which manuscripts a text is before and other texts and in which it is after the same other text. That is for example I want to know all the manuscripts where text "A" is before "B" and all the manuscripts where text "B" is before text "A".

Comment: before updating my answer with the last clarification, do you want to get both lists of manuscripts, (A before B, and B before A) in the same query? or do you plan to have one query and use it twice with reversed text order?

Comment: oh, it could be in two queries, or in one, does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer, yes, order attribute on edge `CONTAINS`, and as for performance, very fast.

> Should I add "order" propertie to the CONTAINS relationship?

Yes, it makes sense to add an order property to `CONTAINS` edges.

Why does it make sense? Let's imagine other places to store the ordering of the texts within a manuscript:

a) Storing the ordering of the texts in the manuscript: In order to be able to do that, you'd need to keep a list of [text,order], to know what text is in what position.

b) Storing the ordering of the texts in the text themselves: In this case, in the text node, you'd need to keep a list of [manuscript,order], to know in what position of the manuscript the text is in, for each of the different manuscripts the text appears in.

While those 2 are valid options for modeling, when you try to perform queries with these 2 different options, you made it harder for yourself when it comes to insert, edit, delete or querying nodes.

> What about performance in requesting for:

Before answering to the concrete scenarios, just a reminder to keep in mind: accessing a node and transversing a relationship in Neo4j, both have a cost of `O(1)`.

**Edit**: additional information about performance in this other [question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769481/4207875)

> get the order list of the texts contening in a specific manuscript

So for a manuscript with `n` texts, the total cost of the operation of retrieving all the texts will be roughly `O(n)`, and have them all sorted, it should be possible to assume a cost of `O(n*log n)`, so will depend on the amount of texts per manuscript.

**Update**: If you want to compare the cost with relational databases, as requested in the comment, well, asuming a similar model, with 3 tables, one for manuscripts, one for texts, and one for the relationship with the order, following the many-to-many with properties approach. You'll end up scanning the whole table of relationships, which will mean that the cost will be higher, as it will deppend on all the existing relationships between all manuscripts and text instead of just a subset.

> know in which manuscripts a text is before and other texts and in which it is after the same other text. That is for example I want to know all the manuscripts where text "A" is before "B" and all the manuscripts where text "B" is before text "A".

Knowing in which manuscripts a text is in, is as easy as transversing all the incoming `CONTAINS` relationships, meaning this operation is `O(n)`, being `n` the amount of manuscripts the text appears in.

But for the manuscripts where a text A appears before a text B, this is a bit more complex, and more expensive, i'll try to break it down:

Given that `n` is the amount of manuscripts the text A appears in, and `m` is the amount of manuscripts the text B appears in.

1. First it will be needed to find all the manuscripts the text A is in, and also all the manuscripts the text B is in. The cost of this operation is `O(n+m)`, which is still linear
2. Then need to filter these lists finding the manuscripts that appear in both lists. This costs again `O(n+m)`.
3. And finally filter again the manifests where the outgoing `CONTAINS` edges, have the order property where the order of `CONTAINS` to text A is smaller than the order property of `CONTAINS` to text B. The cost of this will be roughly `O(k)` where `k` is the size of the list of manuscripts, result of the step 2.

For this case, when using relational databases, will be required to scan the whole relationship table, which will be less performant, as it will be dependant on the amount of rows on the table, instead of just the subset.

Comment: what do you mean about "manifest" ? I will update my question.

Comment: oh snap, i meant manuscripts, dunno why i changed it in my mind. i'll update and change those

Comment: Ok, but I still not understand "If you try to store it in the Manuscript, you'll end up embedding all the texts in the manuscript, and if you intend to do that, better use a document store.". In any case, my question is "to get the order of the texts in a manuscritpts, is it better to use relational or graph database". Is in both the time will be O(n*log n) ?

Comment: @Maïeul finished updating the question, hope it helps, and if there is anything you don't understand, dont hesitate to ask, and i'll try to clarify it.

Comment: "This case, compared to relational databases, again, will be required to scan the whole relationship table again, which will be less performant, as it will be dependant on the amount of rows on the table, instead of just the subset." > I thinks you mean " using relational databases", as you want to tel that graph is more performant than relational

Comment: wops, corrected the expression, and yea, thats what i meant.

Comment: thinks. You confirm my quick intuitions in all your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Both are sensible.

It is easier to maintain if you create a :NEXT relationship between your texts.

For an order property you have to update all of them if you remove or insert one text.

When adding new texts you just append them at the last text with a :NEXT relationship.

Then you can fetch all texts of a manuscript in order with:

```
MATCH (m:MS {id:"..."})-[:CONTAINS]->()-[:NEXT*0..]->(text:TXT)
RETURN m, collect(distinct text);
```

Comment: ok, but in this case I should mark the [:NEXT*0..] relationship with the manuscript identifiant, as the same text can be in multiple manuscript.

Comment: normally, it should not add texts between texts. A manuscripts was written one, and is not modified after it ;-)

Comment: well, with this approach you will get them already sorted, and the first query performance gets better, down to `O(n)`, but need to be careful, because a text can appear in more than one manuscript, so perhaps the `NEXT` edges would require a property with the manuscript id.